# Laravel Migration File

Tags: laravel

I am new in Laravel. I am facing a problem.

I have created a migration file using `php artisan make:migration create_test_table` command.

Then it created a file with the current date/time prefix. I open that file and create a database table in it. Then I ran `php artisan migrate` command, but it didn't create a table in database.

Then I edit the name of the file and put old date/time prefix and ran `php artisan migrate`command, it creates the table in database.

Can anybody tell me why this is happening? How can I fix this? Please help.

Comment: if you wer doing this few times you have some migration logs and an additional table or two in your database. Try deleting all the tables in that test database and try to migrate again

Comment: What you mean by old date/time?

Comment: What error message do you see when you run `php artisan migrate`?

Comment: Can you add migration codes which refusing to work.

Comment: Paste the filename that work and the one that does not.

Comment: No error, it shows "Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'employees' already exists". 

"Employees" is another table and "test" is another table.

Comment: "2014_04_12_000000_create_employees_table.php" this filename works.

"2017_04_20_081449_create_test_table.php", this not works. If I replace it with "2014_04_12_000000_create_test_table.php", then it work.

Comment: Delete line from migrations table `DELETE FROM migrations WHERE migration = 'create_test_table'` and try to run your migration again. Use `php artisan migrate:rollback` to rollback your migrations in future.

Comment: I tried migration command many time. But no success. One more thing, I created "test" file and table in it and ran migration command, then it shows 
"Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'employees' already exists"

while "employees " is the another table.

Answer (score 0):

I think your migration file name *2017_04_20_081449_create_test_table.php* already store in migrations table so, you can remove *2017_04_20_081449_create_test_table.php* name from migrations table in your Database, after that you need to run `php artisan migrate` command.

Hope this work for you!

Comment: I have deleted all my migrations file and also drop the database. Now I have created new database with the same name and made new migration file. i.e. '2017_04_21_043525_create_pet_table.php'.
Then I run 'php artisan migrate' command and it shows :--

Comment: 'Migration table created successfully.

  [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes (SQ
  L: alter table `users` add unique `users_email_unique`(`email`))

  [PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes'.

And then I checked my database. It shows only two tables : migrations and users.

Comment: Its weired but I have deleted 'user and password_reset migration files' and then ran 'php artisan migrate' command. Now newly tables are created successfully.

Can anybody explain me why it is ?